# T_STRING error on line that just says <?php

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I'm writing a script in codeigniter, and I get the following error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/globalar/public_html/givinghusband.com/system/application/controllers/sizes.php on line 1
```

the only problem: the only thing on that line is this:

```
<?php
```

So I'm quite mysterified as to what's going on here? Have I typed PHP wrong or what?

Comment: Is there anything on line 2, perchance?

Comment: Check whether all your ";" are correct.

Comment: or 3 or whatever the next non-empty line is.

Comment: Should there be something special on line 2/3? I just put a blank line for readability.

Comment: Not "should", but "could". You may have made a mistake a few lines ahead, and by posting just the one you're not letting us see it.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with your editor when it updated the file. I just had this problem and the editor removed all line breaks.

If you are uncertain try opening your php file in another editor or use the Cpanel file manager to take a peak.

Comment: If you are using Cpanel, I suggest you try checking the file with the file manager

Answer (score 0):

Or you may have an unterminated quote or statement on some previous line without an ending semicolon (;) . Check all files that are included before this one.

Answer (score 0):

a bare `<?php` in the file leads to a parse error in php (don't ask). Try adding a whitespace or a newline after it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.A bit late but might helpful for others.Just looked at your question.Just use

```
 <? 
 ?>
```

instead of :

```
 <?php 
  ?>
```

and remove whitespaces/line breaks between your php open tag and class name  .It will resolve this conflict.Ta